# jquery each on new elements not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, each

```
$('.collapse').each(function() {
  var title=  $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('a');
  $(this).on('show hide', function (e) {
    if(!$(this).is(e.target))return;
    title.parent().toggleClass('active', 300);
    title.parent().hasClass('active') ? $('input.party').prop('value', '') : $('input.party').val(title.siblings('.delete').prop('id'));

    var id = title.siblings('.delete').prop('id');
    var data = {id: id};
    $.post("times.php", data, function(result) {
      if(title.parent().hasClass('active')){
        $('.times').html('');
      } else {
        $('.times').html($.parseJSON(result));
      }
    })
  })
})
```

So I am adding a new accordion-group to my html by adding a new party and I wan't all this to work on the newly added elements as well. I didn't find topics that could help me since it is a bit more specific than any random `each` function (I think).
This future elements thing is new to me, so I would appreciate some explanations or a good link to a place other that the jquery website which I already checked.
Thank you for your time!

Basically what I want to do this replace `$(this).on('show hide', function (e) {` with something like `$(document).on('show hide', $(this), function (e) {`. What I just wrote doesn't work though.

Comment: You can always only select element that exist. `$('.collapse')` will only select existing elements with class `collapse`. If you want to apply those commands on "future" elements, you have to run the same code on the new elements once they exist (i.e. after you created them).

Comment: whould not it be better to apply the on() method in all the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about the event handler, then you can use [*event delegation*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to capture the event on dynamically created elements as well.

There is not reason why you have to use `.each` here, so just omit it:

```
$(document.body).on('show hide', '.collapse', function() {
    var title =  $(this).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('a');
    if(!$(this).is(e.target))return;
    // rest of the code...
});
```

Comment: I don't actually have a clue why I used it in the first place, I got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this will apply on any new objects matching selector

```
jQuery(document).on('show hide', '.accordion-heading a', function(event){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Notice my first line of code  $('.collapse').each(function() {, this wont let me use $(document).on('show hide', $(this), function(e){ which is what I want to do. Replacing the bit you told me to will just brake everything, I won't toggle classes or anything.

Comment: @Sergo: I don't see a reason why you iterate over all the elements.

Comment: @Sergo you can't assign a future element event handler if not provide a selector for de on() method, because you already done it to a single element, not a selection of them. Would you post an HTML example of the structure?

Comment: Felix nailed it, but you were in the right direction. It was my bad for using each anyway :-(